# How to delete everything after every a specified word in vim

Tags: vim, regex

so i have this string

```
fruit banana
fruit apple
fruit grape
planet jupiter
planet mars
planet saturn
```

And I want to change those string to like this

```
fruit
fruit
fruit
planet jupiter
planet mars
planet saturn
```

The question is, how can I do this with a vim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least 5 ways to do it:

#### With a substitution

With substitutions you can do many things (see `:help substitute`). One is that
you can remember the first word with a capture group by enclosing that part
with `\(` and `\)`, matching the rest of the line (but not remembering it) and
then replacing the line with the remembered group using `\1`:

```
:%s/\(fruit\).*$/\1/
```

#### With normal commands applied to range of lines

You could specify the lines you want to affect and give a normal mode command
to be applied to each line (see `:help :normal`):

```
:1,3norm Sfruit
```

This means, for lines 1 to 3, apply the normal mode command `Sfruit`, where `S`
means 'delete lines and start insert' and then you just type what you want on
the line (see `:help S`).

#### With the global command

You can also apply normal commands to lines matched by some pattern (see `:help global`):

```
:g/^fruit/norm wd$
```

This will apply only to lines with the word 'fruit' appearing at the start (you
can imagine more elaborate patterns in other scenarios). The normal mode
commands `wd$` mean:

```
w   " move cursor forward one word
d$  " delete until end of line
```

(although we could have used `Sfruit` again)

#### With a macro

Another way would be to record a macro (see `:help macro`) such as `qa0wd$jq`
(notice it uses the same method as above). You can then replay the macro with
`@a` and repeat it many times with `@@`, or apply it to all lines with `:%norm @a`(or you could use a range/pattern to specify the lines like above). This
breaks downs as follows:

```
qa  " start recording macro into the 'a' register
0   " move cursor to the beginning of the line      
w   " move cursor forward one word
d$  " delete until end of line
j   " move cursor down to the next line
q   " finish recording the macro
```

#### With block selection

You can also select the words you want by switching to visual block mode with
`Ctrl`+`v` (see `:help visual-block`), highlighting the part of the file you
don't want with regular vim motions (you can press `o` to put the cursor on the
other/opposite corner of the selection block) and finally pressing `d` to
delete the selected content.

Comment: Wow thanks for perfect and complete explanation